# Specify error message for new ActiveRecord validations (presence)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, sinatra-activerecord

I've run into an interesting situation. I was wondering how I could specify error messages with the new `ActiveRecord` validation syntax,

Whereas the old way was:

```
validates_presence_of :person, message: "Sorry, you're not present!"
```

I've tried:

```
validates :person, presence: {true, message: "Sorry, you're not present!"}
```

But that doesn't work... and I can't seem to find any examples of it in the ActiveRecord docs... Does anyone know the syntax?

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

`validates :person, presence { message: "blah blah" }, uniqueness: { message: "blah blah" }`

Answer (score 1):

You could find it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message). Try this,

```
validates :person, presence: true, message: "Sorry, you're not present!"
```

Comment: That didn't work for me... I was also wondering what happens in the case your validating multiple conditions on a single validation line? It's weird how the docs provide examples for every case except the messages for the new syntax...